# Total Spent Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

So with my sheet, I am currently in the process of adding more stats in, I have looked into adding these stats by using Index & Match however it will only match to the first correct match it has not all.

[image: Is an image]

So pretty much I am trying to get stat sheet filled by having it turn the corresponding colors in my KEY into their respective types. So the red in the below photo will condense into the red in the above photo.

[image]

I tried doing this by copying all the cars in the key below the main stats I want and making individual stat sheets per category then using a =SUM to make the final sheet

[image]

I will attach the Spreadsheet [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EeLL0QLKj5jZdE2H_6BCW12H-CEQMeRRoMW0e1POJgk/edit?usp=sharing), I will attempt to answer questions if asked but I need to sleep after spending too much time trying to figure this out. I am new to all this so any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- paste in **C19** cell and drag down:

  ```
  =COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER('Repair Jobs'!$G$4:$G, 'Repair Jobs'!$G$4:$G=$B19)))
  ```
- paste in **D19** cell and drag down:

  ```
  =SUM(IFERROR(FILTER('Repair Jobs'!$F$4:$F, 'Repair Jobs'!$G$4:$G=$B19)))
  ```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much for yet again helping, Each time I get to learn more things about these sheets. Thank you very much for that.